# regexpr with preg_match(), pattern generate error

Tags: php, regex

In an old version of the docebo cms
There is a check with preg_match(), which however generates error and returns false,
Obviously there is something that does not go in the pattern
But probably with an older PHP version it worked
Does anyone know where the mistake is, And how would it be corrected?

```
$str="my_session";
clean_input_keys($str);

protected function clean_input_keys($str) {
    $pattern = '#^[&a-zA-Z0-9\.:_/-\s]+$#uD';
    $b_preg_match = preg_match($pattern, $str);
    var_dump($b_preg_match); //false //preg_match() returns FALSE if an error occurred. 
    if ( ! $b_preg_match) {
        exit('Disallowed key characters in global data.');
    }
    return $str;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Apple developer library? Did you read the error message?

Comment: The fragment `/-\s` doesn't seem to be valid. I would suggest `/\s-` instead.

Comment: Exactly, right now that tries to specify a _character class_ "from / to whitespace" here, which of course makes no sense. (Btw., next time quote the error message please, instead of just telling us that you got one ...)

Comment: And I doubt this ever "worked" in older PHP versions ... much more likely that previously the error reporting was simply silenced, and this never did what it was supposed to in the first place ...

Answer (score 2):

Note that [`preg_match`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) returns false if there is an error in the pattern:

> `preg_match()` returns 1 if the pattern matches given subject, 0 if it does not, or **FALSE** if an error occurred.

The error [PHP throws](http://ideone.com/XK3fwh) is

> PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 19 in /home/VaTQ68/prog.php on line 5

The unescaped hyphen inside a character class may form a range. A range between `/` and `\s` is not defined, hence the error.

You need to put the hyphen at the end or start of the character class, or escape it:

```
$pattern = '#^[&a-zA-Z0-9\.:_/\s-]+$#uD';
                                ^
```

See the [PHP demo](http://ideone.com/0OTDLH)